# Unable to clear up tmp

Tags: linux, unix, tmp

I had a bunch of files in `/tmp` that I cleared up by doing `$ rm -rf ./tmp/*`. However, I'm still unable to 'clear' that information, even after a reset. Here is what I have now:

```
$ cd Av-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
$ df -i
df: no file systems processed
```

I should have roughly 400GB free space on this machine. How can I clear up this space, what do I need to do so that I can create temp files once again? And why isn't `df -i` returning anything?

The distribution I'm using is:

```
Linux version 3.13.0-29-generic (buildd@toyol) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rm` doesn't clear files, it unlinks them. If there were files in `/tmp` open by some processes that are still running, their space hasn't been released. One way to fix the issue is to restart these applications if you can identify them. A simpler workaround is to reboot your OS.

There can be a different source of a `/tmp` full situation. If `/tmp` is based on `tmpfs`, you might just be out of virtual memory.

Comment: They should also use `lsof -n | grep -i delet` releated to your good suggestion about deleted files that were in use.

Comment: Another good answer for this at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68523/find-and-remove-large-files-that-are-open-but-have-been-deleted

Comment: Linux Distribution added in the question. It's ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

you can use following command which will remove everything from /tmp directory which were last modified before 24 hours.

```
tmpwatch --mtime --all 24 /tmp
```

Comment: I see no evidence suggesting this would help at all.

Comment: please see the redhat archive page, link is gien below
https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2004-January/msg04730.html

Comment: How does that differ from what was tried already?

Comment: one problem has many solutions, so i suggested one of them !!

Comment: Except what you have provided is **not** one of the solutions for the problem described in the question. Pay close attention to what was already tried, and why it did not work.